# JQuery MVC loading a string into a text display box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Hey, i have an asp.net mvc2 web app and im using jquery to call controller actions so i can get filtered dropdownlists. I also have some text boxes that should auto populate to information that relates to selected items in the dropdownlist.

I know how to create events that control on change, but where im stuck with is what to have the return value of my controller action if its just a string, and how to set the value of an html.displaytext box to that returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simple set return type of your controller action as string and you can simple make a get call to fetch value from controller. below is basic code for same assuming

```
public string GetTextBoxValue(int selectedIdInDropDown){
       //fetch your text value 
       return myText;         
}
```

In javascript simply call this controller as below:

```
$(function(){
    $.get(
         '/Controller/GetTextBoxValue',
         {selectedIdInDropDown: $('#dropDownId').val()}, 
         function(text){ 
              $('#textBoxId').val(text); 
        })      
 });
```

I hope this helps you,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your response type should be `text/plain` and your callback function should look like this:

```
function setDisplayText(text) {
  $(my_display_text_element).val(text);
}
```